# Given probability of event

Tags: probability

If I'm given the probability that a certain event will occur, how can I find the probability of at least $x$ events occurring given $y$ opportunities?

For example, the probability of a single coin landing heads is 50%. What are the chances of landing at least 2 heads out of 5 coins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model event $E$ happening as a Binomial random variable, that is, if the probability of event $E$ happening is $p$, then the probability of it happening exactly $m$ times in $n$ trials is:
$$\mathbb{P}[X=m]=\binom{n}{m}p^m (1-p)^{n-m}.$$

Since the event consisting of $E$ happening exactly $m_1$ times means the event didn't happen $m_2$ times ($m_1\neq m_2$), the events $X=m_1$ and $X=m_2$ are disjoint, and the probability of a certain set of events happening is the sum of the corresponding probablities.

Comment: so then the probability that the event will happen AT LEAST m times would be sigma of that formula?

Comment: ok i think this is correct. thank you